# Organic Groups for grouping users?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I have a project where I want to group users. So for example, say we have a role of 'King' and a role of 'Subject'. I will have a view where a King can see a listing of all of their subjects. When a new user registers, they will sign up under the name of a King, so they will self-organize as to who they are a subject of.

Is Organic Groups an appropriate module for this functionality? I've watched a few tutorials, and it seems to be about sharing (or actually hiding and providing special access to) content. Here I'm not really so concerned about content, but rather grouping users.

If not Organic Groups, is there a good module for grouping users? This is for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, organic groups would work great for this. You can easily just hide links to the group frontpages.

Comment: How would you actually go about it? From all the tutorials, they talk about marking a piece of content for a group. How would I mark a user as belonging to an og, and then have a display of groups for the users under a particular group?

Comment: You don't need to mess with the content types if you don't intend to use them in group contexts. og adds a group selector to the signup form by default, but you might need to implement some hook_form_alter magic to make it radioboxes instead of checkboxes.

The rest is covered by the organic groups documentation.