# how to group users with similar role with organic group?

Tags: 7

I am working on a site where I want to group all the users having content editor roles to content editor group and all the users having content creator roles to content creator group.How do i do that with organic group ?thanks in advance :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Organic Groups for grouping users?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5072/organic-groups-for-grouping-users)